# Magento module Grid for custom Model is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, database, grid

I scoured the internet and read a dozen tutorials for an answer to no avail.

 The grid is there but there are no rows, only the title and a grey bar under. I manually added  3 rows myself and I'm sure there is some data to display.

This is my `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <mynamespace_mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </mynamespace_mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>mynamespace_mymodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mymodule_resource</resourceModel>
            </mymodule>
            <mymodule_resource>
                <class>mynamespace_mymodule_Model_Resource</class>
                <deprecatedNode>mymodule_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
                <entities>
                    <rfmgroups>
                        <table>mymodule_rfm_groups</table>
                    </rfmgroups>
                </entities>
            </mymodule_resource>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>mynamespace_mymodule_Helper</class>
            </mymodule>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <mymodule>
                <class>mynamespace_mymodule_Block</class>
            </mymodule>
        </blocks>
        <resources>
            <mymodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>mynamespace_mymodule</module>
                    <class>mynamespace_mymodule_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_setup>
            <mymodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_write>
            <mymodule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mymodule_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>mynamespace_mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <mymodule module="mymodule">
                <title>mymodule</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <mymoduleindex module="mymodule">
                        <title>Dashboard</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>mymodule/dashboard</action>
                    </mymoduleindex>
                    <mymodulerfmgroups module="mymodule">
                        <title>RFM Groups Management</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>mymodule/rfmgroups/index</action>
                    </mymodulerfmgroups>
                </children>
            </mymodule>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <mymodule translate="title" module="mymodule">
                            <title>mymodule</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <mymoduleindex translate="title">
                                    <title>mymodule Dashboard</title>
                                </mymoduleindex>
                                <mymodulerfmgroups translate="title">
                                    <title>mymodule RFM Groups</title>
                                </mymodulerfmgroups>
                            </children>
                        </mymodule>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

This is my `layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mymodule_rfmgroups_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/rfmgroups" name="mymodulerfmgroups" template="mymodule/rfmgroups.phtml"/>
            <!--<block type="mymodule/rfmgroups" name="mymodulerfmgroups"/>-->
        </reference>
    </mymodule_rfmgroups_index>
</layout>
```

This is the Model located in `app/code/local/namespace/mymodule/Model/RfmGroups.php` :

```
<?php

class namespace_mymodule_Model_RfmGroups extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mymodule/rfmgroups');
    }


}
```

This is the resource model located in `app/code/local/namespace/mymodule/Model/Resource/RfmGroups.php` :

```
<?php

class namespace_mymodule_Model_Resource_RfmGroups extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mymodule/rfmgroups', 'group_id');
    }

}
```

The resource setup located in `app/code/local/namespace/mymodule/Model/Resource/Setup.php` :

```
<?php

class namespace_mymodule_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
{
}
```

And my controller located at `app/code/local/namespace/mymodule/controllers/RfmGroupsController.php` :

```
<?php
class namespace_mymodule_RfmGroupsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_title($this->__("mymodule RFM Management"));
        $this->_setActiveMenu("mymodule");
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/rfmgroups'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

My SQL file located at `app/code/local/namespace/mymodule/sql/mymodule_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` :

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
    CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('mymodule/rfmgroups')}` (
    `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `r_min` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `r_max` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `f_min` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `f_max` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `m_min` int(5) NOT NULL,
    `m_max` int(5) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`group_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

This is my block class located at `app/code/local/namespace/mymodule/Block/RfmGroups.php` :

```
<?php

class namespace_mymodule_Block_RfmGroups extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'rfmgroups';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'mymodule';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('RFM Groups');

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }

}
```

This is my grid class located at `app/code/local/namespace/mymodule/Block/RfmGroups/Grid.php` :

```
<?php

class namespace_mymodule_Block_RfmGroups_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Set a unique ID for our grid
        $this->setId('rfm_groups');
        // Default sort by column
        $this->setDefaultSort('group_id');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/rfmgroups')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('group_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('ID'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'width' => '60',
            'index' => 'group_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Name'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'width' => '200',
            'index' => 'name',
            'type' => 'varchar'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('r_min', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('R min'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'width' => '60',
            'index' => 'r_min',
            'type' => 'int'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('r_max', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('R max'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'width' => '60',
            'index' => 'r_max',
            'type' => 'int'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('f_min', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('F min'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'width' => '60',
            'index' => 'f_min',
            'type' => 'int'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('f_max', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('F max'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'width' => '60',
            'index' => 'f_max',
            'type' => 'int'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('m_min', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('M min'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'width' => '60',
            'index' => 'm_min',
            'type' => 'int'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('m_max', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('M max'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'width' => '60',
            'index' => 'm_max',
            'type' => 'int'
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

}
```

The layout and template files are in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule.xml` and `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mymodule/rfmgroups.phtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was I didn't have a collection class in `app/code/local/namespace/mymodule/Model/Resource/RfmGroups/Collection.php` like so:

```
<?php

class namespace_mymodule_Model_Resource_RfmGroups_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('mymodule/rfmgroups');
    }
}
```

My Grid was trying to find a non existent collection. I should have paid more attention to my models.